# Laravel Scout:import not importing data to ElaasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-scout

When i run the following command on my VM, it shows that records are imported but actually data were not imported

```
php artisan scout:import 'App\Models\File'
```

Solutions i have tried.

- scout queue is set to false
- Configuration is seems ok

I have noticed one more thing that when i write query on tinker to search, then its returning correct result using scout. But only import / searchable() function is not working.

Note: I have the same branch on another serve and it works fine there. But not sure why its not working on my VM.

Let me know if any additional detail required. Any suggestion would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Could you be sure the hosts of your scout configuration are pointing to the correct server you want to ingest data? It saves the documents somewhere if it says it saved. But that server could be legacy or your local environment instead of you desire to ingest.

Comment: No i don't think so. I have checked my env file and the scout_host is set to http://127.0.0.1:9200 which is localhost for my VM.